# Additional whitespace in HTML table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, cell

I can't find out why the most simple example of a table cell fails miserably (in FF29). Please see http://jsfiddle.net/aYWG9/:

```
<body>
<table style="border-spacing:0">
  <tr>
    <td style="background:red;padding:0;margin:0;border:0">
        <img src="http://rufiojones.files.wordpress.com/2011/08/foghorn_leghorn.gif"/>
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body
```

Where do the extra 5px come from, and how can I remove the red space? (Don't tell me to change the color!)

Comment: Not only in FF. I see the red space in Chrome as well. Can't tell where it comes from.

Comment: By default an `<img>` is an inline element, so there needs to be space for the *descender* part of a letter, if you do, `img { display:block }` that will fix the issue, and make the img behave like a block level element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Images,_Tables,_and_Mysterious_Gaps is a very old article, but explains the issue in a bit more detail.

Comment: @NickR That would have been a nice answer, but the points go to Andy now.

Comment: `display: block` is also a solution. There is a slight difference, in that adding something else into the cell will cause it to appear below the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image behaves, by default, as a text-character, with a gap at the bottom to display the over-hang of a letter (its descender).

Use the vertical-align property to get rid of it:

```
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: I like the display:block as well, hard to choose...
Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/aYWG9/9/

```
<img style="display:block;margin:0;padding:0" src="http://rufiojones.files.wordpress.com/2011/08/foghorn_leghorn.gif" />
```

the margin and padding to 0 to remove all other style in your css file. But you can put to in you css file:

```
 td img{display:block;margin:0;padding:0;}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this style:

```
img{display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;}
```